# Navigation to a different screen in jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, navigation-compose

The layout I want to achieve is the following:

- Three (3) destinations on the bottom app bar
- The first destination ( HOME ) has bottons to access other destinations, for example a settings screen which is opened in full screen.

Here is the code I have now adapted from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav):

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            Scaffold(
                bottomBar = { NavBar(navController = navController) }
            ) { paddingValues ->
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screen.Overview.route,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues),
                ) {
                    composable(route = Screen.Overview.route) {
                        OverviewScreen() <--- this screen can access other screens
                    }
                    composable(route = Screen.Transactions.route) {
                        TransactionsScreen()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the overview screen, I have the following:

```
@Composable
fun OverviewScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    
) {

    
    val overviewNavController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = overviewNavController,
        startDestination = <--- current screen IS the main screen of this graph
    ){

        composable(route = Screen.Settings.route){
            SettingsScreen()
        }
        ...
    }
```

This code works correctly but for example the settings screen should NOT have the buttom bar visible!
Hence I cannot declare them within the main NavHost graph.

How to achieve this ? What construct allows me to do this?
I don't mind restructuring the entire code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have made an example for you. I have used Material3 And Latest Android Studio Version.

Just Replace You Drawable Icon

**Example**

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsetsSides
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.only
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.safeDrawing
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.windowInsetsPadding
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Settings
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.material3.CenterAlignedTopAppBar
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBar
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItem
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationBarItemDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.ImageVector
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavDestination.Companion.hierarchy
import androidx.navigation.NavGraph.Companion.findStartDestination
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.currentBackStackEntryAsState
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController

@Composable
fun Ex11(
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = NavRoute.Home.route,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        composable(route = NavRoute.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen() {
                navController.navigate(it)
            }
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Settings.route) {
            SettingsScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Home(navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Button(onClick = {
            navigateTo(NavRoute.Settings.route)
        }) {
            Text(text = "Click Me")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SettingsScreen() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Settings Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit
) {

    val topLevelDestinations = listOf(
        TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen1.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.home,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.home_outline,
            iconText = "Home"
        ), TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen2.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.bulb,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.bulb_outline,
            iconText = "Generate"
        ), TopLevelDestination(
            route = NavRoute.Screen3.route,
            selectedIcon = R.drawable.my_files,
            unselectedIcon = R.drawable.my_files_outline,
            iconText = "My Files"
        )
    )

    val showBottomBar = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var title = remember {
        mutableStateOf("AI Art")
    }
    val navController = rememberNavController()




    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {


        CenterAlignedTopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
                text = title.value,
                color = Color.White,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
            )
        }, colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        ), actions = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Settings,
                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                contentDescription = "Settings",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .clickable(interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                        indication = rememberRipple(
                            bounded = false, radius = 22.dp, color = Color.Black
                        ),
                        onClick = {
                            navigateTo(NavRoute.Settings.route)

                        })
                    .padding(8.dp)
            )
        })

        HomeNavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f),
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavRoute.Screen1.route,
            navigateTo = navigateTo
        )
        if (showBottomBar.value) {
            HomeBottomBar(destinations = topLevelDestinations,
                currentDestination = navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination,
                onNavigateToDestination = {
                    Log.e(Constants.TAG, "onCreate: Navigate $it")
                    title.value = when (it) {
                        "my_files" -> "My Files"
                        "generate" -> "Generate AI Art"
                        else -> {
                            "AI Art"
                        }
                    }

                    navController.navigate(it) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }
                        restoreState = true
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                })
        }
    }

}


@Composable
fun HomeNavHost(
    modifier : Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    startDestination: String,
    navigateTo: (route: String) -> Unit
) {

    NavHost(
        navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination, modifier = modifier
    ) {

        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen1.route) {
            Screen1()
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen2.route) {
            Screen2()
        }
        composable(route = NavRoute.Screen3.route) {
            Screen3()
        }


    }
}


@Composable
fun Screen1() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "One Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen2() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Two Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}

@Composable
fun Screen3() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text(text = "Three Screen", fontSize = 20.sp)
    }
}


@Composable
private fun HomeBottomBar(
    destinations: List<TopLevelDestination>,
    currentDestination: NavDestination?,
    onNavigateToDestination: (route: String) -> Unit
) {
    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface) {
        NavigationBar(
            modifier = Modifier
                .windowInsetsPadding(
                    WindowInsets.safeDrawing.only(WindowInsetsSides.Horizontal + WindowInsetsSides.Bottom)
                )
                .height(70.dp),
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
        ) {
            destinations.forEach { destination ->
                val selected =
                    currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == destination.route } == true
                NavigationBarItem(
                    colors = NavigationBarItemDefaults.colors(
                        selectedTextColor = Color.White,
                        unselectedIconColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        unselectedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                    ),
                    selected = selected,
                    onClick = { onNavigateToDestination(destination.route) },
                    icon = {
                        val icon = if (selected) {
                            destination.selectedIcon
                        } else {
                            destination.unselectedIcon
                        }
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(icon),
                            modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text(
                            text = destination.iconText
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will look into this and try to figure out the structure.